# My TableView initializes before JSON data is received. How do you prevent this?

Tags: swift

I am coding an app that receives air pollution data from API. The code passes JSON from aqicn.com. The data is updated too slowly and the tableview is displayed first. So there isn't any data displayed for the data view. I have tried DispatchQueue.main.async but it did not work. Delays using DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter did not work. Been stuck on this for several days now. Please give me suggestions or solutions!

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var pm25Data:Int?
    var pm10Data:Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        performRequest(with: "https://api.waqi.info/feed/Tainan/?token=\(C.APIkey)")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
    }
    
    func performRequest(with typeURL: String)
    {
            if let url = URL(string: typeURL)
            {
                print("pass")
                let session = URLSession.shared
                print("pass")
                let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil && data != nil
                {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    do
                    {
                        let info = try decoder.decode(AirData.self, from: data!)
                        self.pm25Data = info.data.iaqi.pm25.v
                        self.pm10Data = info.data.iaqi.pm10.v
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    } catch
                    {
                        print("we have an error")
                    }
                    }
                }
                dataTask.resume()
            }
        
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        
    }
    override open var shouldAutorotate:Bool
    {
        return false
    }
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.descriptionName?
                .text = "PM 2.5"
            cell.valueNumber?.text = "\(pm25Data)"
        }
        else
        {
            cell.descriptionName?.text = "PM 10"
            cell.valueNumber?.text = "\(pm10Data)"
        }
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Fetching the data from a network request obviously will take time depending upon the network speed. Till that time if you don't have data you won't have anything to display in the tableView. What is the problem with that?

Comment: But I don't know how to update the tableview.

Comment: So, the data you get from api does show up in the table view after you reload it, right?

Answer (score 0):

**One possible way...**

Maintain an array of objects containing the data for each row, I will call it `dataArray` so that each object in the array would contain the information required to populate each respective row. Then, in your `cellForRowAt` function, after dequeueing the cell like you currently have implemented, do something like this:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    cell.descriptionName?.text = "PM 2.5"
    cell.valueNumber?.text = "\(pm25Data)"
    // Other setup unique to the first cell
} else {
    cell.descriptionName?.text = dataArray[indexPath.item - 1].description
    cell.valueNumber?.text = dataArray[indexPath.item - 1].description
    // Other setup unique to all following cells
}
```

Also, implement your `numberOfRowsInSection` with one line, simply `return dataArray.count`

Then, once your `dataArray` is filled with objects containing the data, call `self.tableView.reloadData()`

**In a broader but still simplified sense:**

Every time you call `reloadData()`, a few things happen:

1. The tableView will call its `numberOfRowsInSection` function
2. The tableView will call its `cellForRowAt` function repeatedly the number of times returned from `numberOfRowsInSection` and set up each row individually
3. The tableView will call other functions like `heightForRowAt` as necessary to set up each row

**Some things to keep in mind:**

1. Call `reloadData()` every time you want to refresh the tableView (with new data, for example)
2. You don't really set up each cell individually, you set up the logic to populate cells with data pulled from an itemized source (usually an array)
3. All you then have to do is maintain the `dataArray` and then call `reloadData()` every time you want to refresh the tableView. The `cellForRowAt` function handles populating each cell with data.

**A useful tutorial:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=VFtsSEYDNRU